# Replacing generated delete method in backend with Symfony

Tags: symfony1, generator, custom-action, backend

I have a bunch of models in my backend application in Symfony. Since these models are related between them through foreign keys, I would like to replace the default delete method with one of my own to check if an object can be deleted or not.

In order to do that I have developed an intermediate class MyActions, which inherits from sfActions, and set `actions_base_class` with `MyActions` in generator.yml.

In `MyActions` class I have put a `executeDeleteIfNotUsed` method, which I want to be executed instead of `executeDelete`.

When it comes to configure the module actions I have made something like this in `generator.yml`:

```
list:
    title: Authorities
    display: [name, updated_at]
    fields:
      name:
        label: Name
      updated_at:
        label: Last update
        date_format: f
    sort: ~
    object_actions:
      _edit:    ~
      _delete: { label: Delete, action: delete_if_not_used }
```

But Symfony still generates routes to `executeDelete`, instead of the one I have defined.

What am I doing wrong? What's the best way to implement this? Do I have to add custom routes besides sfDoctrineRouteCollection?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like you're making this more complicated than it needs to be. I would just stick with the regular actions class, and override the delete method with your own custom one.  This way you know your code is being used, and you don't have to mess around with the generator.yml

**Edit**

Based on your comment, I see why you want to do it the way explained in your question. Changing the action for the `_delete` in generator.yml won't work. I'm not exactly sure *why*, but I'm fairly sure it has something to do with the fact that it's a Javascript request. Instead, add a new custom action.

```
list:
  object_actions:
    _edit: ~ # This ensures your edit action remains unchanged
    delete_if_not_used: { label: Delete, action: action: delete_if_not_used }
```

Note that the actual action method and the action name in generator.yml must match. In your original question you were using the method `executeDeleteIfNotUsed` and had `delete_if_not_used` in generator.yml.   This won't work because as far as Symfony knows, those are two completely different methods. I would suggest just using `deleteifnotused` in generator.yml

Comment: I want to capture the exception `Model->delete()` raises and redirect the user to another page. That's why I made it in controller actions, not model methods. I've already implemented that in frontend and it gave me no problems. And I need the intermediate class because this should be made in several modules

Answer (score 1):

I think you are not doing it in the right way. You just have put your delete logic in the delete() method of the **Model**. It's the best practice and recommanded way to do.

You have even nothing to change on the generated admin action, because it use the delete() method of your object:

```
if ($this->getRoute()->getObject()->delete())
{
  $this->getUser()->setFlash('notice', 'The item was deleted successfully.');
}
```

Also, putting this logic in the Model will allow you to have a more consistent way to delete entity.

Comment: As I told @Arms, I need the intermediate class because this should be made in several modules. I do not want to replicate the same logic in several classes. Maybe the solution is to add a intermediate model class

Comment: Ok, in that case, you can also write your own Admin Generator, this way you can write the delete action the way you want (and much more!).

Comment: @Damien, while I think using a custom admin generator is a good thing, it's complete overkill for what elitalon is trying to accomplish. Writing a new generator takes A LOT of time :)

Comment: @Arms, not that much, he just have to copy/paster the whole generator folder into a plugin of his own and customize the delete action generator template. I don't know if it's documented but that works fine. I using this technique to add a show action on my generated admins too.